# React hook error when use built package from webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

I've making a library and tried to use built package on example code by doing this

```
import { createMiddleware, useActionListener } from "../../../../lib";
```

It occurs an error `Invalid hook call.` at

```js
  useActionListener("SUB", (action) => {
    //...
  });
```

So I tried to publish a package and changed like this

```
import { createMiddleware, useActionListener } from "myLibraryName";
```

And it works like charm.

I have no idea why calling built package direct occurs an error. Any ideas?

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'reactActionListener',
    globalObject: 'this',
  },
  externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
    },
    redux: {
      root: 'Redux',
      commonjs2: 'redux',
      commonjs: 'redux',
      amd: 'redux',
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.tsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      // Needed when library is linked via `npm link` to app
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
    },
  },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|ts|tsx|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Just to clarify - webpack compiles your "../../../../lib" to "myLibraryName". So is works as intended, no?

Comment: @LiorPollak Then, is there a way to use built package directly?

Comment: You said that when you import like this import { createMiddleware, useActionListener } from "myLibraryName";
it works?